# Alterar Selectonemenu

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Estou trabalhando com as tabelas Pais, Província e Município, usando JSF, Primefaces e EJBs. Mas ao executar o Projeto dá o seguinte erro:

> javax.faces.FacesException: /localizacao.xhtml @131,83
>   value="#{utilBean.AProvincia.fkPais.pkPais}": Target Unreachable,
>   'null' returned null

Meu Bean:

```java
public void gravarProvincia() {
   provinciaFacade.create(NProvincia);
   NProvincia = new Provincia();
}

public void alterarProvincia() {
   AProvincia.setFkPais(new Pais(AProvincia.getFkPais().getPkPais()));
   provinciaFacade.edit(AProvincia);
   AProvincia = new Provincia();
}

public void removerProvincia() {
   provinciaFacade.remove(AProvincia);
}

public List<Provincia> todasProvincias() {
    return provinciaFacade.findAll();
}
```

Meu XML:

```xml
<p:dialog id="dlgAProvincia" widgetVar="w_dlgAProvincia">
   <p:panelGrid columns="2">
      País:
      <p:selectOneMenu value="#{utilBean.AProvincia.fkPais.pkPais}">
         <f:selectItem itemLabel="Escolhe o Pais"/>
         <f:selectItems value="#{utilBean.todosPaises()}" var="aProvinciaPaisVar" itemLabel="#{aProvinciaPaisVar.descricao}" itemValue="#{aProvinciaPaisVar.pkPais}"/>
      </p:selectOneMenu>

      Província:
      <p:inputText value="#{utilBean.AProvincia.descricao}"/>
   </p:panelGrid>
   <center>
      <p:commandButton value="Gravar" action="#{utilBean.alterarProvincia()}" oncomplete="w_dlgAProvincia.hide()" update="frmPais"/>
      <p:commandButton value="Cancelar" oncomplete="w_dlgAProvincia.hide()"/>
   </center>

</p:dialog>
```

Answer (score 1):

Na Bean crie um método chamado init e inicie o objeto Pais dentro do objeto Provincia assim:

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
   AProvincia = new Provincia();
   AProvincia.setFkPais(new Pais());
}
```

O Nullpointer se da porque tentou acessar o objeto Pais dentro de Provicincia que estava não estava instanciado, estava nulo.